# A new tool for structure recovaribility of disks in linux - what is missing?

Tags: backup, hard-disk, data-recovery

I have disks that after power breaks may structurally fail. Any back up tools fail to "save" or "restore" the previous good structure. I think the reason for that is that some random sectors / blocks were off.

see [here details](https://superuser.com/questions/1810384/after-power-breaks-gparted-fdisk-reports-that-ssd-disk-has-incorrect-table-h)

In almost any such situation using testdisk, I found that tree structure have become a looping structure.

`dirA-> file A file B file (it was file C became dir) file C.dir -> dir A -> file A file B file C.dir --> dir A -> file A file B ......`

I think that file c existed on a sector that before problem a folder was on that sector. The sector went off and reading gpt now gives a file with folder attributes etc.

What tools / info is missing to repair the structure in such cases:
All current tools fails (gdisk, fdisk all *disk tools).

A tool that is able to save which files/folders occupies which sectors.
So a file occupies sectors 1 to 4, folder occupies sector 6 etc.
Having a good backup and then taking a back up from the bad disk,
the tool will be able to align files / folder structure in current sector-situation.

Good situation

```
tree_sector_info_tool (plus attributes?)
folder Z 5bytes: sector 1
-file A 100kb: sectors 2 to 10
-file B: sectors 11 to 20
```

Bad situation (so file b is not recoverable).

```
tree_sector_info_tool
folder Z 5bytes: sector 1
-file A 100kb: sectors 2 to 10
-file B.dir: sectors 11 to 12
```

How this can be done with any existing tool? is possible?
(the hard part will be to align/compare the info with the info existed in disk).
However it means that bad sectors ARE able to be detected and in what position they exists.
And it means that looping can be detected (cause testdisk cannot leave from looping).

Hardware recommendation: Bios / Linux have for power loss data-prevention?
Disks may contains batteries for power-loss cases?